# Counter this claim, If [T]CB is diagonal for some ordered bases B and C, then T is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the claim is false and thus there exists a counter example for it. I have gathered that it is possible for T not to be diagonalisable if B consists of non-eigenvectors but I can't think of an example to demonstrate this.

Comment: Did you mean $\;[T]_C^B=\;$ the matrix of $\;T\;$ wrt basis $\;B,\,C\;$ ? For $\;T\;$ to have any chance of being diagonalizable it must be a linear transformation from an $\;n\,-$ dimensional vector space to an $\;n\,-$ dimensional vector space, 
 and then it is customary to identify both vector spaces in one single space and take the same basis (i.e., we have a linear operator) .... Please do add more info.

Answer (score 0):

Given any linear map $T: V \to W$ between finite-dimensional vector spaces, we may always choose bases $B \subseteq V$ and $C \subseteq W$ such that the matrix ${_C}[T]_B$ looks something like
$$ {_C}[T]_B =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
where the number of $1$'s is the rank of $T$. (Think about how you would find these bases $B$ and $C$, they are quite easy to define).

Applying this to the special case of a linear endomorphism $T: V \to V$, we know that we can always pick bases $B$ and $C$ which make ${_C}[T]_B$ diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

The archetype for non-diagonalizable matrices is 
$$
S = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}.
$$
It's about as simple as you can get (consisting of only 1s and 0s), and it's non-diagonalizable because it lacks a basis of eigenvectors. (The evalues are both zero, but if there were two independent evectors with evalue zero, the matrix would have to be the zero matrix!) There's no $1 \times 1$ example of a non-diagonalizable matrix, so this really is the simplest possible example.

Let $T$ be the transformation on $\Bbb R^2$ sending $v$ to $Sv$.

Consider the basis $B$ consisting of $e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $e_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1}$, and the basis $C$ consisting of $e_2$ and $e_1$ (in that order!). Then $$
{_C}[T]_B = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$$
(or perhaps you need to swap $B$ and $C$ to make this true...I can never remember the order).

Anyhow, that matrix $S$ is worth carrying around in your pocket. It provides counterexamples to just about everything. (I exaggerate, but...)